# Copy files after the current copy operation is completed

Tags: copy-paste

I sometimes need to copy a lot of files from here and there to an external drive. What I do is copy some files, paste it in the drive, copy some more files, then paste again etc. But this makes the files copy parallelly which slows down the drive.

Is there a way (maybe a third-party app to install) that would queue the second copy until the first copy operation is completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Pathfinder](http://www.cocoatech.com/pathfinder/) from Cocoatech
   It's called `Queue file operations` or `Copy queue`:

   Open in the menubar Windows -> File Operations (or shortcut: <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>) and enable `Queue file operations`. All file operations (like copy, move etc.) will be queued then.

   [image: queue]
2. [CopyQueue](http://www.curiosoftware.com/copyqueue/index.html) from Curio Software

   You have to define new tasks (New Queue or <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>) first.
   You may save them, if you have to use certain copy operations repeatedly.

   [image]

Comment: Thanks! PathFinder looks really great. Still worrying whether the huge price would be worth it. Going to try out the trial.